# Avoiding switch statements

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Consider the following piece of code:

```
double computeK(unsigned short choice, double R){
   switch (choice){
      case 1:
        return 1.0/R;
        break;
      case 2:
        return log(R);
        break;
      case 3:
        return exp(-R);
        break;
      case 4:
        return exp(-R*R);
        break;
      case 5:
        return exp(-R);
        break;
      default:
        return 1.0/R/R;
        break;
   }
}
```

The user calls this function many times for different values of `R` from another class which he calls from his input file, but the value of `choice` remains the same for each input file. Is there a way to avoid this switch statement? (I can write a makefile, have appropriate tag for `choice` and ask the user to change the value of tag in the makefile but the user wants to call the function from his input file without making changes from the makefile.)

I would greatly appreciate if you could provide the associated code as well.

Thanks

Comment: Why is it that you want to avoid the switch statement in the first place?

Comment: @Borgleader The function gets called tons and tons of times and I am wondering whether the switch statement will make the code go slower.

Comment: Premature optimization, if you haven't profiled that it is a bottleneck, chances are it isn't. Switches are actually pretty efficient.

Comment: -1 for give-me-the-codez

Comment: @sehe: what runs noticeably quicker without the switch statement?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Everything! Even quicker without main(). Seriously, I just posted my answer

Comment: Keep in mind that switch statements will often be compiled into jump tables.

Comment: If you're worried about the switch slowing down your code, just remove it entirely.  After all, the fastest code is code which does nothing at all!

Answer (score 3):

The C++ approach would look like:

**Update** Since it is apparently not self evident, this is what is fixed:

- it takes the switch out of the loop (you say that `choice` will remain the same for all values). The switch is ***only done once***
- it takes care to *allow* the compiler to ***fully inline the `computeK` call*** (this is not necessarily the case with function pointers, though compilers are smart these days and will spot the ability to do so on occasion). This might become a big performance win when the call is surrounded by *actual computations*.

Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

template <typename ComputeK>
   void RunBatch(std::vector<double> const& data, ComputeK const& computeK)
{
    for (double element : data)
    {
        double k = computeK(element); // TODO useful work
    }
}

int main()
{
    int choice = 3; // TODO input
    std::vector<double> data(10000); // Demo only, could be streamed from input
    switch (choice){
        case  0: RunBatch(data, [] (double R) { return   1.0/R;     }); break;
        case  2: RunBatch(data, [] (double R) { return   log(R);    }); break;
        case  3: RunBatch(data, [] (double R) { return   exp(-R);   }); break;
        case  4: RunBatch(data, [] (double R) { return   exp(-R*R); }); break;
        case  5: RunBatch(data, [] (double R) { return   exp(-R);   }); break;
        default: RunBatch(data, [] (double R) { return 1.0/R/R;     }); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You know.. that's just the OP's original code, with a loop on a vector, right? It changes nothing about the aspect he wanted to change- the `switch`.

Comment: @DeadMG Why is everybody so dense? The OP is worried about the switch executing too often (every time it's called). ***That changed***. Hurrah

Comment: Well... not really. Your solution only functions if the OP knows all the data in advance before performing any processing, and can process it all together *and* all the data fits in memory, etc, which is not stated.

Comment: @DeadMG Bullshit. I chose a vector, but that's not necessary. What did I do wrong that you attack an answer with ridiculous claims?

Comment: @sehe: dont' take DeadMG personally, that's just the way he is and you know it.

Answer (score 2):

If `choice` is know at compile time, you can use templates to choose which specialization to call:

```
template<int choice>
void computeK(double R);

template<>
void computeK<1>(double R)
{
    return 1.0/R;
}

template<>
void computeK<2>(double R)
{
    return log(R);
}
```

and you call as:

```
computeK<2>(R);
```

Comment: The questioner clearly states that he reads the choice in from the input file.

Comment: No, the question clear make an assumption that user can choose at the Makefile or in source input file, not reading a data file

Comment: Huh, you're right. I read the whole Makefile thing as "Makefile is out because user", but he does suggest it might be possible. If he can convince the user to set the value in the Makefile, then a template would be a very viable option.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=cbda0a682c5777b00d5b432ef9e389f7-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Comment: I didn't really have a point.  I was merely showing that your suggestion can be applied with minimal changes to his code.  Weather that's a good thing or not is for other people to decide.

Answer (score 2):

Switching on `choice` with a "unknown" value is probably 4-10x faster than calculating `1.0/R`, and 10-100x faster than `exp(R);` or `log(R);`

If `choice` is always the same, the branch prediction will kick in and decide that "Oh, it's usually 2 here, so lets preload and start execute choice 2".

Using function pointers is probably not really worth the effort, because you will end up making a call instead of a predicable conditional jump - so not very likely to give you any benefit.

If `choice` is a hard-coded constant in the calling code, putting this function in a header file and letting the compiler inline it will remove the entire switch. But if it's a variable read from a file, then it's a different story.

Finally, maybe doing a different split of the code would help - e.g. instead of passing in a single `double`, pass in a `const vector<double>& R, vector<double> K` and calculate 10, 100 or 100000000 values of the `K` values from the `R` values.

And as always when dealing with optimisation/performance, benchmark, compare different solutions, preferrably on more than one platform.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the usual schtick about profiling and stuff.

Secondly, the `switch` is going to be as efficient as possible. It's simple contiguous values, the compiler can transform it into a function-local jump table trivially. Plus, branch prediction if you keep calling with the same `choice` is going to make this easymode for the CPU to execute in nearly, if not sometimes absolutely, in zero time.

Note that all solutions based on storing function pointers or function objects *are* a jump table, they're just non-local and much more difficult for the compiler to optimize -> slower performance.

Edit: If, in fact, you can convince the user to provide the value in a Makefile, then a template would be a quite viable option. I read the question as banning this but other answerers didn't so it's kinda ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Simply break up your big function into several simpler functions, for example:

```
double computeK3(double R){
    return exp(-R);
}
```

and while you are reading the input, decide which function do you want to call (maybe by a switch statement) and then store the pointer to that function.

Now, you can use that pointer to call the right function.

In that case you'll go through a switch statement only once, so that's an improvement.

Comment: So you have a bunch of small functions instead of the one with the switch. Now what?

Comment: @MichaelBurr He is worried by going through the switch statement many times, so in this case, he can decide which function to call. The simplest solution as it can be.

Comment: But he has to decide which function to call... in a switch statement? :D

Comment: @pkacprzak: so instead of having the decision made by a switch statement in the `computeK()` function, you have the decision made by something outside.  What's making that decision - another switch statement?

Comment: @Pixelchemist maybe, but he could decide it once and store the pointer to the function rather than go through the switch every time

Comment: So now we're getting somewhere (even if I'd guess that the added complexity wouldn't really buy much of a perf improvement - but who knows?).

Comment: Why not have the client call the right function? Passing in a choice parameter is a pretty weird API anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use the Table-driven with Function Object or function pointer
for example:

```
typedef double (*FunPtr)(double r);
FunPtr Handle_Table[6] = {handle1Fun, handlele2Fun....};
....
return Handle_Table[choise](r);
```

done.

Answer (score -1):

I would create an array of function pointers, each function represents a different operation:

```
std::vector<double (*func)(double)> opList;
```

Define somewhere each index (e.g. choice) to point to a different function, define the functions so they take in an R value and return the result.  Then, instead of a switch statement, you access the array index of the opList array and use it like a function:

```
double computeK(unsigned short choice, double R) {
    return opList[choice-1](R);
}
```

Each function in your function pointer list would look something like this:

```
double Choice1(double R) {return return 1.0/R};
```

Comment: Bam. Gone are the chances of inlining